How to handle a popup that only appears sometimes?
After logging in to landing page a popup will appear but it only appears sometimes. but I can't able to handle it properly.
Cypress.Commands.add('closePopupIfPresent', (popupSelector, buttonSelector) => {
try {
    cy.xpath(popupSelector).then((popup) => {
        if (popup.length > 0) {
            cy.wrap(popup).should('be.visible').then(() => {
                cy.xpath(buttonSelector).click();
            });
        } else {
            cy.log('Popup not present');
        }
    }
    )
} catch (error) {
    cy.log('Error in closePopupIfPresent command:', error);
}

});
Error:

Timed out retrying after 30000ms: Expected to find element: //*[@id='__dialog8'], but never found it.


Apart from a very brief description there's nothing here that shows how the page is constructed or how it works. It's going to be difficult to see how to fix your code when we have no idea what it's working with.
